# EF core memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a query that fetches around 2000 records from database, and I noticed that every time I run that query (call the endpoint) memory goes up by 30 MB and in the end server runs out of memory. 
Even if `DbContext` is disposed. 
But when I add `AsNoTracking()` to query, memory stays the same all the time, no leak. This seems like bug in `EF Core`. Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: Read this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: I know what tracing is, I ask why entities being tracked stay in memory after context has been disposed and thus creating memory leak.

Comment: Did the Garbage Collector run?

Comment: Yes, I tried running GC manually also, and still the same. It seems AsNoTracking() did not help actually, I was looking wrong things. Memory leak is there even with AsNoTracking().

Comment: Sounds like false assumptions on your side. Does your application really runs out of memory (crashes with `OutOfMemroy`exception) or does the memory just grow up w/o (apparently) being released? If its later one, thats normal behavior of server garbage collection (it only does memory compaction when OS is running into memory pressure, not before that)

Comment: @Tseng You are right, no OutOfMemory exception, its just that in the end server is like 50 MB from total capacity, and this same request triggered at that time returns 500 error. So I assumed it doesnt not have enough memory to be served. But I think I need to investigaste this a bit more and post more detailed observations here.

Comment: If you get 500 status code, there is also an exception

Comment: Whenever you have a query that pulls a lot of records, I would re-evaluate the logic and see if there's a way to allow the database engine to do some logical pruning on the data. I've seen several enterprise systems suffer the same effects you are witnessing because the database query was pulling way to much information when a bit of critical thought could significantly reduce the data returned.

Comment: @Aleksa disposing the context doe not dispose/remove the data/entities retrieved from the database. If you use these objects (and holding them somewhere) these objects will be seen by the GC as "being in use" and not be reclamed (normal GC behaviour). Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have (preferable as a [mcve]).