# Suspicion of a memory leak in EF Core

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I was faced with the fact that EF Core (version 5, .Net 5), leaving a significant cache after disposing the dbcontext.

The question like this but newer:

[EF core memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685315/ef-core-memory-leak)

Here's a simple example:

- Console Application (.NET 5).
- Training database `AdventureWorks2019` on SQL Server 2019
- `DbAdventureWorks2019Context` contains 2 entities, `Person` and `Address`, from schema `Person` of `AdventureWorks2019`

The code sample:

```
public void ReadPerson()
{
    using (var context = new DbAdventureWorks2019Context())
    {
        var locpers = context.Persons.ToList();
    }
}

public void ReadAddress()
{
    using (var context = new DbAdventureWorks2019Context())
    {
        var locaddr = context.Addresses.ToList();
    }
}

public void ReadN2()
{   //heap 65
    ReadPerson(); //heap 1550
    ReadAddress(); //heap 1709
    ReadPerson(); //heap 1711
    ReadAddress(); //heap 1725
    ReadPerson(); //heap 1757
}
```

Here are memory snapshots from VS performance tool after calling `ReadN2()`.

This snapshots were taken after each function call.

The first snapshot was taken before the first function was called.
Using `QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking` or `AsNoTracking` reduces but does not remove the memory leak.

Is there any way to release the memory?

[snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXr9K.png)

Comment: Garbage collection does not happen instantaneously. You have code in a using block which will dispose.  What I think is happening is you still have links to the context.  Copying to a list is not copying the data just creating links to the context so memory is not going down.  Try : var locpers = context.Persons.Select(x => new {person = x}).ToList();

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't help. I think it's not related to garbage collection, because code:
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
 didn't help and links in the example only local and expression "_ =" instead of "var locaddr = " doesn't change anything.
In snapshot most of the links that appeared are RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache

Comment: I said I didn't think it was GC.  You still have links to the data and that is why the memory was not released.

Comment: Yes. But these links created EF Core and largest memory is contained in links with intermediate root MemoryCache (from dump). I don't know how I can control the caching.

Comment: The only way you can reduce the memory is to release the memory (the links).  If you application is still using the memory you cannot dispose these values.